# Binary Search w/o Library Methods

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary-search, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to construct a binarySearch method that goes through a *sorted* array, and evaluates whether a given element, given as **int target**, is present. It will do so by evaluating whether the mean value is greater or less than the target value, and will loop through the first or second half of the array accordingly.

I think I have the basic code down, but I am running into some problems:

- int target = 0; (returns true) => correct
- int target = (3, 6, 9); (returns false) => should return true
- int target = (15, 19, 21, 90); returns "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15" => should be true

I imagine it has to do with my for statements in the respective if cases, but I have tried to debug and cannot. Also, I not permitted to use library methods.
Hopefully this question is helpful for other beginners like me. I would think it explores some java concepts like syntax, logic, and basic use Thanks for the help.

```
public class ArrayUtilities
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  int[] arrayBeingSearched = {0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 19, 21, 90};
  int target = 90; 
  System.out.println("linear: " + linearSearch(arrayBeingSearched, target));
  System.out.println("binary: " + binarySearch(arrayBeingSearched, target)); 

}



public static boolean binarySearch(int[] arrayBeingSearched, int target)
 {

  boolean binarySearch = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayBeingSearched.length; i++){
  int left = 0; //array lower bound
  int right = arrayBeingSearched.length - 1; //array upper bound
  int middle = ((right - left) / (2)); //array mean

  if(arrayBeingSearched[middle] == target){
   binarySearch = true;
  }
  else if(arrayBeingSearched[middle] < target){

    for(int j = middle + 1; j < arrayBeingSearched.length - 1; j ++){
      int newLeft = arrayBeingSearched[j ++];
      if(arrayBeingSearched[newLeft] == target){
      binarySearch = true;
      break;
      }
      else{
        binarySearch = false;
      }

    }
  }
  else if(arrayBeingSearched[middle] > target)

    for(int l = 0; l < middle - 1; l ++){
      int newRight = arrayBeingSearched[l ++];
      if(arrayBeingSearched[newRight] == target){
      binarySearch = true;
      break;
      }
      else{
        binarySearch = false;

      }
  }

  else{
    binarySearch = false;
  }
}

return binarySearch;
}

}
```

Okay, based on the comments, would this be a better representation? The first comment answered my question mostly but I just wanted to follow up:

```
public static boolean binarySearch(int[] array, int target)    
    {  
        int start = 0;  
        int end = array.length - 1;  

        while (start <= end)   
        {  
            int middle = start + (end - start)/2;  
            if (array[middle] == target) {  
                return true;  
            }  
            else if (array[middle] > target)    
            {  
                end = middle - 1;  
            }  
            else start = middle + 1;  
        }  
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad start:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayBeingSearched.length; i++)
```

That's a linear search, with something else within it. I haven't followed exactly what you're doing, but I think you should probably start again... with a description of binary search in front of you.

Typically a binary search loop looks something like:

```
int left = 0;                            // Inclusive lower bound
int right = arrayBeingSearch.length;     // Exclusive upper bound
while (left < right) {
    // Either change left, change right, or return success
    // based on what you find
}
```

Comment: @nicky478: Yup, that should do it. You've used an inclusive upper bound instead of an exclusive one, but that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

When your middle element is smaller than the target, you do this

```
int newLeft = arrayBeingSearched[j ++];
if(arrayBeingSearched[newLeft] == target) //...
```

And the equivalent when it's larger.

That is, you are taking an element of the array and using it as an index. Your array could contain only one element with a value of 1000, which is why you're running into an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other problems (see Jon's answer), but I wanted to mention that code like this:

```
for(int j = middle + 1; j < arrayBeingSearched.length - 1; j ++){
  int newLeft = arrayBeingSearched[j ++];
```

will not do what you want.  The `for` statement says that each time the program goes through the loop, it will add 1 to `j` (at the end of the loop code).  But the next statement will use `j` as an index and then add 1 to it.  The result is that each time you go through the loop, 1 will be added to `j` *twice*, so you're basically looking only at every other element.  If this were otherwise correct (which I don't think it is), I'd say you definitely need to remove the `++` from the second line.